# Creating a fat jar for Dropwizard application

Tags: jar, maven-plugin, dropwizard, fat

I am trying to create a fat jar for a multi module java project following the dropwizard documentation that makes use of the maven shade plugin.

https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/getting-started.html#building-fat-jars

In order to do this I created another aggregator project which is just another pom.xml and configured the plugin in this pom.xml

Is there a way I can add my classpath in this configuration? What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just creating the fat jar from your dropwizard POM?

Comment: Yes, if I use the parent pom , it throws an exception. Followed this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147512/using-maven-shade-plugin-in-a-multi-module-project-nullpointerexception

Comment: This is why I like gradle :) I used the shadow plugin and it worked really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those interested. I fixed the issue by forcing Guava version 12 that the application gets from dropwizard.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. Especially if you have found a solution to your problem.